# symfony form - render same widget multiple times

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I'm not sure if I can use symfony collection type to achieve below form. PS: the list of social media channels is coming from yaml config as array. So for each channel I have to call the form type class and only have 1 submit button.

```
<form action="...">

Facebook:
 - Now (checkbox)
 - later (checkbox)
 - <hidden input field value="facebook">

Instagram:
- Now
- later
- <hidden field value="instagram">

Twitter:
- Now 
- later
- <hidden field value="twitter">


- submit 

</form>
```

This is what I have right now in twig:

```
{% for channel in channels %}
    {{ form_widget(form.channel, {'attr': {'value': channel }}) }}

    {{ form_widget(form) }}
{% endfor %}
```

of course it won't work because the same field will be rendered several times and it will break on validation.

The build method still the basic example on how using ChoiceType:

```
$builder->add('options', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices'  => [
                'Not yet' => null,
                'Now' => false,
                'Draft' => false,
                'later' => false
            ],
            'expanded'  => true
        ])
->add('channel', HiddenType::class)
```

So, how to render the same widget multiple times in Symfony form?

Comment: That's too broad to fit in a single answer, but this can be done [this way](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html)

Comment: @cid not sure about this approach. The symfony doc is describing one Task with many tags and using `allow_add  => true`. It is not the same use case described above. I have pre-defined channels (fixed in configuration) and I need the same widget for the different channels.